# transformable property of NSManagedObject expects NSNumber

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, transformable

I use core data for storage and need to save `UIColor` to an `NSManagedObject`. I have a property for that which is set to be transformable and assign it like this

```
[managedObject setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"colour"];
```

And get a weird error saying

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "colour"; 
desired type = NSNumber; given type = UIDeviceRGBColor; value = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.4 1 0.8 1.
```

Obviously, the colour in the example used is not black, but this works for any colour whatsoever, my main problem is that the I have no idea why is a transformable attribute expecting an NSNumber when I never assigned one to it before

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a custom model object class? Was it auto-generated?

Comment: It is custom, but I have assigned this attribute to be transformable. I can just save the rgb values, however it would be a lot easier if I could store the UIColor itself so first wanted to check whether is there no way to do it.